# Ninject parent child container hierarchy (like inheritance)

Tags: inheritance, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container, ninject

Does `Ninject` have anything similar to the `Unity` concept of parent/child containers to provide a basic inheritance model? I googled but didn't find anything.

Comment: This may be a late answer, and since is not Ninject related I put is as comment, but there's another good IoC framework (not feature complete like Ninject, but maybe more appropiate for Unity)
https://github.com/sebas77/Lightweight-IoC-Container-for-Unity3D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ninject supports container hierarchies using https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.childkernel. See also my article http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/12/08/how-to-use-the-additional-ninject-scopes-of-namedscope/ about additional scopes for Ninject. Expecially look at the last part. Sometimes it is better using this concept rather than container heirarchies.

Answer (score 2):

There are Activation Blocks. Not aware of specific documentation, but the [Cache and Collect article](http://kohari.org/2009/03/06/cache-and-collect-lifecycle-management-in-ninject-20/) has an example. I'd look in the tests for more examples.

I'm sure @Remo Gloor will be along but I believe the general attitude of the team (and original author) are that Nested Containers are A Bad Idea and hence are not likely to be supported directly in the core (but it may be via an extension - e.g., like [Context Preservation](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/12/08/ninject-extension-contextpreservation-explained/)